# Install Windows two times, each one thinks it is on "C"?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I'm having two SSD drives in my machine (let's call them SSD A and SSD B)

I run Win 8.1 on SSD A, SSD B is empty.

From the view of Win 8.1 SSD A has the drive letter C, and SSD B has the drive letter D.

Is it possible to install Win 10 on SSD B **AND** make SSD B appear as C, SSD A as D whenever I run Win 10? If yes, how? If no, why not? Are drive letters not a Win-only concept?

Comment: The online [booted to] Windows install will always mount to `C:`, as it's hard coded into Windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, if you use generic Windows Setup or using any install tools. Using Windows Setup will automatically set the destination drive letter, always C. And SSD A is always show as D when boot into SSD B.

No, drive letters not a Win-only concept. Drive letters in Windows are inherited from DOS.

Comment: A "little" late, but thanks, maybe it helps someone else in the future :-)